# Domino en haskell

Tags: haskell

Estoy empezando en `haskell` y seguramente mi duda pueda ser resuelta muy fácil.

El caso es que estoy tratando de generar en una lista, las **fichas del dominó** (tuplas del tipo `Integer,Integer`) mediante una lista generadora.

Sería algo así:

```
domino :: [(Integer,Integer)]
domino = 

[(n1,n2) | n1 <- [0,1,2,3,4,5,6], n2 <- [0,1,2,3,4,5,6],(PARTE INCOMPLETA)]
```

El caso es que en el domino **si el par (1,2) está, no puede estar el (2,1)**. Supongo que tengo que imponer una condición pero no sé cómo.

Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta con que el primer número sea menor o igual al segundo.

```
[(n1, n2) | n1 <- [0..6], n2 <- [0..6], n1 <= n2]
```

Puedes hacer que directamente la segunda lista genere los números desde `n1` hasta `6`. Así las fichas no se repiten y evitas tener que filtrar los pares que sobran.

Por otra parte, deberías utilizar el tipo de datos `Int` en lugar de `Integer`. `Int` es para enteros comúnmente de 32 o 64 bits (depende de la implementación, pero se garantizan al menos 30 bits), mientras que `Integer` es para enteros de longitud arbitraria.

```
domino :: [(Int, Int)]
domino = [(n1, n2) | n1 <- [0..6], n2 <- [n1..6]]
```